# SSE instruction need the data aligned

Tags: x86, sse, simd

Must the data be 16-byte aligned so that it can be processed by the SSE instruction without segmentation fault? The compiler I tried is gcc with option `-msse2`. I want use `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` to compare a large int array. I found that it can not be executed at any location of the array except the position with subscript of the multiples of 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, when you load and store data to/from SSE registers it needs to be 16 byte aligned, *unless* you use the misaligned versions of the load/store instructions, e.g. `_mm_loadu_si128`/`_mm_storeu_si128`. There is typically a performance penalty for using these misaligned load/store instructions however, so one would normally try to ensure correct data alignment at all times and only use misaligned loads/stores as a last resort.